# Mongodb $lookup on multiple fields

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections, `products` and `properties`.

I'm doing a lookup such as:

```
[{
        $match: {
            category_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(category_id)
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "properties",
            localField: "category_id",
            foreignField: "category_id",
            as: "properties"
        }
    }
]
```

This is basically getting me all of the products that match the category_id and including the properties that match the same category_id.

I need to add an additional check, for `some_id` on the `properties` result.  In otherwords, the `properties` should be grouped by the `some_id` that is returned from the `products` collection and matches the same key in `properties`.  Does that make sense? Basically having the ability to have multiple local/foreign field definitions.

any idea how I could this?

Comment: Any sample data available? Like input data and then desired output.

Comment: Have you tried `$filter` ? Something like `{
    $addFields: {
        properties: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$properties",
                as: "result",
                cond: {
                    $eq: ["$$result.some_id ", "$some_id"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 4):

Since version 3.6 we can use uncorrelated sub-queries

```js
    {
       $lookup:
         {
           from: '<collection to join>',
           let: { <var_1>: '<expression>', …, <var_n>: '<expression>' },
           pipeline: [ '<pipeline to execute on the collection to join>' ],
           as: <output array field>
         }
    }
```

This allows us to to have more than a single equality match on the lookup.
See also: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/